# Efficient way to check whether triangles are similar

Tags: triangles, ratio

If we need to find if a triangle is isosceles, we can compare like a=b, b=c and a=c. But there are 3 comparisons. With $(a-b)(b-c)(a-c) = 0$, we can check it with **one** comparison.

Usually for similar triangles we do $a/x=b/y=c/z$ method. Can anybody show me a way with one comparison to do it (checking whether two triangles are similar)?

Comment: Do you want to check, if the triangles are similar or if they are isosceles ?

Comment: similar- with one comparison or less

Comment: Less than one comparison ?

Comment: sorry, not less ,least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangles with the sides $a,b,c$ and $x,y,z$, where $0<a\le b\le c$ and $0<x\le y\le z$, are similar iff

$$\frac{a}{x}=\frac{b}{y}=\frac{c}{z}\iff\left(\frac{a}{x}-\frac{b}{y}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b}{y}-\frac{c}{z}\right)^2+\left(\frac{c}{z}-\frac{a}{x}\right)^2=0$$

Answer (score 1):

The triangles with the sides $a,b,c$ and $x,y,z$ with $a\le b\le c$ and $x\le y\le z$
 are similar if and only if

$$\pmatrix{a\\b\\c}\times \pmatrix{x\\y\\z}=0$$

Comment: Please can you put the proof or (its link) here ?

Comment: The cross product of non-zero vectors is $0$, if and only if one vector is a multiple of the other. This is equal to the property $\large \frac{a}{x}=\frac{b}{y}=\frac{c}{z}$ in case of positive entries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.It gave an answer :)